# Как VS code при клике на файл что бы открывались дополнительные окна?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Как VS code при клике на файл что бы открывались дополнительные окна? Он открывает но если я на еще одно окно хочу открыть то он его заменит, а мне нужно что бы было несколько окон открыто

Comment: Once you have to open your settings file, add the "workbench.editor.enablePreview" property and set value to false.